# Issue in Incrementing array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In my project I increase values of firstArray +3.After I increase values of secondArray  +7 .

```
   $firstArray = array(
      'a' => 1,
      'b' => 3,
      'c' => 5,
   );

foreach ($firstArray as &$item) {
    $item += 3;
}
print_r($firstArray);
```

**Result:** `Array ( [a] => 4 [b] => 6 [c] => 8)`

```
  $secondArray = array(
    'a' => 11,
    'b' => 13,
    'c' => 17,
);

foreach ($secondArray as $key=>$item) {
    $secondArray[$key] += 7;
}

print_r($secondArray);
```

**Result:** `Array ( [a] => 18 [b] => 20 [c] => 24 )`

**But** problem is when I did `print_r($firstArray) again;` I have this result:
Array ( [a] => 4 [b] => 6 [c] => 17 )

Why there is the difference in result fisrt and thisrd?

Comment: Where you get `Result: Array ( [a] => 12 [b] => 22 [c] => 32 )` from?

Comment: this all code in one php page, this all 2 loops

Comment: Edited. I pasted firrst wrong resulr, sorry.

Comment: Because you're looping with a __reference__ (`&`) in the first loop, you need to `unset($item)` immediately after that loop otherwise it's still a reference to the last entry in `$firstArray`... looping `by reference` should always be approached with caution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you used $item **as a link**, and after one loop you used it again(I think after reuse $item some of value were rewritten ). You need to **unset($item)** after first loop, and even alwas unset link after used them.

```
$firstArray = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 3,
    'c' => 5,
);

foreach ($firstArray as &$item) {
    $item += 3;
}
print_r($firstArray);

unset($item);
```

**Now result is good**

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array_map` instead of loops and pass-by-reference. You avoid mutation this way. For example:

```
$add = function($x) {
  return function($y) use($x) {
    return $x + $y;
  };
};

$firstArray = array_map($add(3), $firstArray);
$secondArray = array_map($add(7), $secondArray);
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not the answer on my question

Comment: The other answer has the solution to your particular issue; this is an alternative solution.